# What is the role of convex optimisation in AI systems?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization

Convex optimisation is defined as:

[image]

I have seen a lot of talk about convex loss functions in Neural Networks and how we are optimising rewards or penalty in AI/ML systems. But I have never seen any loss function formulated in the aforementioned way. So my question is:

Is there any role of convex optimization in AI? If so, in what algorithms or problem settings or systems?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any role of convex optimization in AI?

Yes, of course!

> If so, in what algorithms or problem settings or systems?

The problem of finding the parameters of a [support vector machine](https://qr.ae/pNvzNm) can be formulated as a convex optimization problem. Another example is [linear regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/194461/82135).

See also the paper [Convex Optimization: Algorithms and Complexity](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.4980.pdf) (2014) by Sébastien Bubeck, which also mentions SVM as a typical example.

Comment: I'll accept the answer after I do a bit of my own research.

Comment: @DuttaA Yes, don't worry. The first thing that came to mind when I read your question was SVM (because I am familiar enough with its details and I used it in the past). Anyway, I only skimmed through the first paragraphs of the paper I am linking to, but it looks like a paper that goes into the direction of your question.